# Does the Wolframalpha app provide step by step solutions?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Several years ago wolfram alpha stopped providing the step by step solution in the browser. However, until last month it was still possible to get a step by step solution using the mobile version of wolfram alpha (maybe they simply forget to restrict it). However, now it seems they fixed it and as I got so much used to checking my differential equations using walpha I was wondering if the Android app does the job or if I have to upgrade to pro.

Answer (score 4):

Running from the website prompts you to buy Alpha Pro.

Trying either "differentiate (x^2 + 3 x) with respect to x" or `D[(x^2 + 3 x), x]`.

[image]

However, calling Alpha from Mathematica works, as posted here:-

[Get a “step-by-step” evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231/363)

```
ShowSteps[exp_] := WolframAlpha[ToString@HoldForm@InputForm@exp,
  {{"Input", 2}, "Content"},
  PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}] 

SetAttributes[ShowSteps, HoldAll]

D[(x^2 + 3 x), x] // ShowSteps
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just WolframAlpha["My Query"] ? Then I can click on "Show Steps"